# Fourier and its inverse

Tags: integration, fourier-transform

Im slightly confused as to how to prove the inverse fourier is true, if we have:
$$F(\omega)=\mathcal{F}[f(x)]=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)e^{-j\omega x}dx$$
$$f(x)=\mathcal{F}^{-1}[F(\omega)]=\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty F(\omega)e^{j\omega x}d\omega$$
then it should be that:
$$\mathcal{F}^{-1}[\mathcal{F}[f(x)]]=f(x)$$
and so:
$$\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(y)e^{-j\omega y}dy\right)e^{j\omega x}d\omega=\frac1{2\pi}\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty f(y)e^{j\omega(x-y)}dyd\omega=f(x)$$
but I cannot find a nice way to simplify this or evaluate the general case. Any ideas?

Comment: Without a rigorous proof $\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty {e}^{i\omega(x-y)}d\omega=2\pi\delta(x-y)$, $\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty{f}(y)\delta(x-y)dy=f(x)$

Comment: @Svyatoslav interesting point, so would I first have to prove that the order of integration can be changed?

Comment: Yes, you are right - it means the change of the order of integration, and the validity of it should be proved.